# Trying to create and download thousands of files not working now

Tags: javascript, download

Ok so I wrote this program to avoid having to manually reformat several >6000 entry csv files by hand. It froze on the first run of the full file, then ran fine when i gave it a 1000 entry chunk i got 1000 files in my downloads folder. Now it won't download more than 51 at a time. The rest are converted to my XML format but they don't automatically download.

```
<script src="./papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var data;
  var j = 1001;
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];

    Papa.parse(file, {
      header: true,
      dynamicTyping: false,
 //     preview: 5,
      step: function(results, parser) {
        j++
//        console.log("Row data:", results.data);
//        console.log("Row errors:", results.errors);
//        $("#test").text(results.data["0"]["correct_answer"]);

var dataArray = [j,
                  results.data["0"]["question_id"],
                  results.data["0"]["node_id"],
                  results.data["0"]["part_text"],
                  results.data["0"]["distractor_1"],
                  results.data["0"]["distractor_2"],
                  results.data["0"]["distractor_3"],
                  results.data["0"]["correct_answer"],
                  results.data["0"]["explanation"]];

dataArray = HTMLGunkCleanse(dataArray);

XMLWriter(dataArray[0],
          dataArray[1],
          dataArray[2],
          dataArray[3],
          dataArray[4],
          dataArray[5],
          dataArray[6],
          dataArray[7],
          dataArray[8]);


      }//end of the line for stuff to do with each iteration of data

      })
    };

function HTMLGunkCleanse(dataArray){
var regex = /<[^>]*>/g;
for (i = 3;i<8;i++){
dataArray[i] = dataArray[i].replace("<p>", "\r\n").replace("</p>", "").trim();
var check = dataArray[i];
dataArray[i] = dataArray[i].replace(regex, "").replace("\\s+", "").trim();
if (check != dataArray[i]){
console.log(check);
console.log(dataArray[i]);  // shows any differences that may have occured
  }
}

return dataArray
}

function XMLWriter(fileName, qID, nodeID, question, d1, d2, d3, correct, feedback){


setTimeout(function(){console.log("waiting");},1)

//create long ugly string that looks good in xml



 var blob = new Blob([doc.toString()], {
 type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
 });

 var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

 var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.download = "cfal_question_00006_" + fileName + ".dita";
 a.href = url;
 a.textContent = "Download latest";
 a.click();
 //if the click() function dosen't work you can try using onclick() fucntion like this
 //a.onclick();


 document.getElementById('test').appendChild(a);
 }


  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#csv-file").change(handleFileSelect);


  });
</script>
<input type="file" id="csv-file" name="files"/>
<div id="test">

</div>
```

In preresponse to question yes i realize its ugly. I've taken one javascript class and don't some stuff online so i'm kinda newish. Any advice on why it was working fine and doesn't work now? I am using Google chrome to run it btw.

Comment: I still have no idea why it worked once but I switched to using [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and its worked great.

Answer (score 0):

In your function 'HTMLGunkCleanse', return dataArray doesn't end with a ';' Maybe that's the problem?